# Previous 30 days via a loop

Tags: php

I need to write a loop to output the last 30 days from yesterday in the following format:

```
2014-02-02
2014-02-03
2014-02-04
...
2014-03-04
```

I think I need to use the loop like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=30; $i++) {
   echo $date;
}
```

Also I know I can find a start date 30 days ago

```
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', time() - (60 * 60 * 24 * -31) );
```

Not sure hot to put all these pieces together (afternoon caffeine deprivation)...

Comment: bad approach, not every day =60 * 60 * 24

Comment: I'd look into using a `DateInterval` which will not have issues with things like leap years. Looks like you just need to replace `-31` with `-1 * $i` inside your loop to create the date for each day.

Comment: Why not store them in array going back 30 days.. and print array out BACK to FRONT

Comment: What do you meant not every day =60 * 60 * 24  ?..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime)

```
for($i = 30; $i > 0; $i--)
{

    echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-$i days"));

}
```